# Why Chrome shows height x width on window resize, how to disable it?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome browser recently started showing me this,

[image]

Also there is some issue with resize components, and not fully resizing components, anyone know how to disable it ?

Comment: What are the "issue with resize components" you're referring to?

Comment: @Nick that's another domain as i am using third party CMS, however issue came up with Chrome, so if anyone else had same issue and found a fix